# Assign regular javascript array to array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have 3 regular arrays in javascript

> 1st array : ids[] (contains list of ids)
>  2nd array : country[]
>   (contains list of names of countries)
>  3rd array : codes[] (contains
>   list of codes of countries)

I need to create an object array say 'comb' from these three arrays having keys as "id", "name" and "code" and the respective values from the 3 arrays.

Eg:
This is what i want from the regular arrays

```
var comb = [
{id:1, name:'United States',code:'US'},
{id:2, name:'China',code:'CH'}
];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this

Comment: Just FYI, the result you have is an array of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var comb = [];
for (var i=0,n=ids.length;i<n;i++) {
  comb.push({id:ids[i],name:country[i],code:codes[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer defining objects this way, I think it looks more readable.

```
function Country(id, country, code) {
    this.id = id;
    this.country = country;
    this.code = code;
}

var comb = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var ctry = new Country(ids[i], country[i], codes[i]);
    comb.push(ctry);
}
```